# What exactly is Socket

Tags: sockets

I don't know exactly what socket means.
A server runs on a specific computer and has a socket that is bound to a specific port number. The server just waits, listening to the socket for a client to make a connection request.
When the server accepts the connection, it gets a new socket bound to the same local port and also has its remote endpoint set to the address and port of the client.
It needs a new socket so that it can continue to listen to the original socket for connection requests while tending to the needs of the connected client.

So, socket is some class created in memory? And for every client connection there is created new instance of this class in memory? Inside socket is written the local port and port and IP number of the client which is connected. Can someone explain me more in details the definition of socket?

Thanks

Comment: I think you got it already...

Comment: Please Check Out http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: In simple terms, socket is used for real time data transfer between server and client

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-in-computer-network/#:~:text=A%20socket%20is%20one%20endpoint,which%20the%20communication%20take%20place.

Answer (score 20):

A socket is effectively a type of file handle, behind which can lie a network session.

You can read and write it (mostly) like any other file handle and have the data go to and come from the other end of the session.

The specific actions you're describing are for the server end of a socket. A server establishes (binds to) a socket which can be used to accept incoming connections. Upon acceptance, you get *another* socket for the established session so that the server can go back and listen on the original socket for more incoming connections.

How they're represented in memory varies depending on your abstraction level.

At the lowest level in C, they're just file descriptors, a small integer. However, you may have a higher-level `Socket` *class* which encapsulates the behaviour of the low-level socket.

Comment: It would be more accurate to say 'behind it lies an *endpoint* of a network session'.

Comment: @paxdiablo Above comment?

Comment: @Suraj, if you're asking what the correct term is, my thoughts are that, whether you specify the *immediate* thing behind a socket (eg, endpoint) or a more collective term (eg, session, "other end", network), it doesn't really have a large bearing on what the socket *is* - it's basically a handle to indicate some connection to elsewhere.

Comment: @paxdiablo Can you pin me to some good resource where I can have a depth understanding of all these terms, and how they work?

Comment: @Suraj, I learnt mostly at Uni which was quite a while ago, but the current reference I have is the W Richard Stevens book "UNIX network programming". It's pretty good in my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

According to "TCP/IP Sockets in C-Practical Guide for Programmers" by Michael J. Doonahoo & Kenneth L. Calvert (Chptr 1, Section 1.4, Pg 7):

> A socket is an abstraction through which an application may send 
>   and receive data,in much the same way as an open file allows an application to read and write data to stable storage. 
>   A socket allows an application to "plug in" to the network and communicate
>   with other applications that are also plugged in to the same network. 
>   Information written to the socket by an application on one machine can be
>   read by an application on a different machine, and vice versa.

Refer to this book to get clarity about sockets from a programmers point of view.

Answer (score 3):

Socket definition:

A communication between two processes running on two computer systems can be completely specified by the association: `{protocol, local-address, local-process, remote-address, remote-process}` We also define a half association as either `{protocol, local-address, local-process}` or `{protocol, remote-address, remote-process}`, which specify half of a connection. This half association is also called socket, or transport address. The term socket has been popularized by the Berkeley Unix networking system, where it is "an end point of communication", which corresponds to the definition of half association.

Answer (score 2):

A network socket is one endpoint in a communication flow between two programs running over a network.

**A socket is the combination of IP address plus port number**

This is the typical sequence of sockets requests from a server application in the connectionless context of the Internet in which a server handles many client requests and does not maintain a connection longer than the serving of the immediate request:

**Steps to implement**

At Server side

```
initilize socket() 
--
bind() 
-- 
recvfrom() 
--
(wait for a sendto request from some client) 
-- 
(process the sendto request) 
--
sendto (in reply to the request from the client...for example, send an HTML file)
```

A corresponding client sequence of sockets requests would be:

```
socket() 
--
bind() 
--
sendto() 
--
recvfrom()
```

so that you can make a pipeline connection ..
for more  http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/tcpip-ports-sockets

Comment: more than one socket can be associated with one local port

Comment: Sockets are *so* much more than an IP address and port number. `AF_INET` is only *one* of the address families, there's a vast number of them such as AppleTalk, DECNet, X.25, and so on. It would be more accurate to state that they represent an arbitrary network endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

I found this article in online.

> So to put it all back together, a socket is the combination of an IP
> address and a port, and it acts as an endpoint for receiving or
> sending information over the internet, which is kept organized by TCP.
> These building blocks (in conjunction with various other protocols and
> technologies) work in the background to make every google search,
> facebook post, or introductory technical blog post possible.

https://medium.com/swlh/understanding-socket-connections-in-computer-networking-bac304812b5c